# Is there a way to format TNumberBox.text?

Tags: delphi, format, firemonkey

I want the displayed text o a TNumberBox to be formatted eg. when value = 0 to show 'zero', showing thousands separator etc.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: If you want custom formatting you'll need to write something yourself.  `TNumberBox` is a primitive control with few options.  It's a minor addition to a `TCustomEditBox` - have a look at how the FMX framework implements it.  I'd suggest rolling your own in the same way, implementing your custom formatting in the `ConvertTextToValue` and `ConvertToText` methods of a new descendent `TEditBoxModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the `OnPaint()` event as follows:

```
procedure TForm14.NumberBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
var
  nb: TNumberBox;
  rf: TRectF;
  tx: string;
begin
  nb := Sender as TNumberBox;

  if nb.Value = 0 then
    tx := 'zero'
  else
    tx := format('%.0n',[nb.Value]);

  rf := ARect;
  Canvas.ClearRect(ARect, TAlphaColors.Lightpink);
  rf.inflate(-4, -2);
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;

  Canvas.FillText(rf, tx, False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Center);
end;
```